# plugin translations not reflected in admin dashboard

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, translation

I have a plugin which has all strings originally in English, now translations to Arabic have been done at 100% and are appearing on the project link. When I check the plugin's page in Arabic, it is working perfectly, but the changes inside the admin dashboard, ex: plugin description and settings page, are still showing the untranslated English strings. Which have been already translated. I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you are passing your plugin domain as an argument in the internationalization:

`__('label example', 'plugin slug')`

and for the description and the plugin name, you should add the
`Text Domain: 'plugin-slug'`